# SPOJ QCJ3 ( Grundy-Sprague + NIM)

Tags: algorithm

Hi came across a problem on SPOJ (http://www.spoj.com/problems/QCJ3/).
I tried to map this problem to the Grundy numbers and then to Sprague-Grundy + NIM piles.
I could deduce the following...

1. If there are only even number of coins placed on any positions/places (1,2,3,4...) the first player always looses.
2. If there are odd coins placed only in 1 position anywhere and even coins placed anywhere the first player wins.
3. Depending on the coins placed at positions (1,2,3,...k-1) movement of coins on K'th position can reach any (next) state depending on the number of coins placed in the previous positions. This I find hard to map to the Grundy Numbers + Sprague-Grundy + NIM piles.

*** I did see a code where the solution is reached by doing a XOR (of positions where odd number of coins are placed). If this approach yields correct result (which of course I have not submitted, because I don't understand "why?") what is the logic behind this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the game with a single coin at position x.

This is the same as playing Nim with a heap of size x.

Now the total game can be viewed as a set of games, one for each coin.  There is a standard result with Sprague-Grundy theory that the value for a collection of games is the XOR of the values for the individual games.

In other words, this game is equivalent to Nim where you have a pile of size x for each coin at position x.  The XOR solution for Nim is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).

Comment: Well, I need not get a pile of size 'X' for position X. (May get less, may get more) and XOR's of all the positions does not give me correct answer. I have verified this. (I understand the reason behind XOR's,  but why XORs on only those **positions** where **odd** number of coins are placed)

Comment: You should not xor all positions but all coins. So if there are three coins at 5,you should xor 5 three times. Now, xor operation is its own inverse and x xor x=0. Thus xoring x 2n+1 times is equal to xoring it once.

Answer (score 0):

This problem maps to NIM so it is solved using XORs because that's the solution to NIM:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/61249180/Game-Theory-Intro-Ak#scribd

> idea: Each stone at position P, corresponds to heap of size P in NIM
>   
>   r = x ^ x ^ x ^ x . . . . . ^ x ( n times ) 
>   
>    - n even : r = 0
>    - n odd : r = x

In this approach, if there are **x** stones at position **n**, then **n** is XORed **x** times because each stone corresponds to a heap size of n.

- XOR of something an even number of times is equal to zero.
- XOR of something an odd number of times is equal to itself.

a simple implementation:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
r=0; 
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x&1) r ^= i;
}
puts(r==0?"Hanks Wins":"Tom Wins");
```

Comment: I understand the XORs operation, but why XORs on only those **positions** where **odd** number of coins are placed.

Comment: Actually number of coins refers to number of XORs of the **position**. So when it's **even** the result will be zero. Check the edit above.

Comment: I think, I understood what you are saying. Will implement it and submit to make sure my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Coin a position P, can be moved to positions (P-1, P-2, ... 3, 2, 1, 0). So a **single coin at position P would be equivalent to 1 NIM pile of size P.**

3 coins at Position 1 => 3 NIM piles of size 1.
4 coins at Position 2 => 4 NIM piles of size 2.

So for the above case the solution would be sol = (1^1^1^2^2^2^2). 
If sol == 0, player 2 (Hanks) wins else Tom wins

```
       for(long long pos=1; pos<=SZ; pos++){
           scanf("%lld", &coins);
           if(coins){
              for(long long i=1; i<=coins; i++){
                  status ^= pos;
              }   
           }   
       }   
       if(status == 0) printf("Hanks Wins\n");
       else printf("Tom Wins\n");
```